# Why am I getting this error trying to update cocoapods?

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, ssl-certificate, cocoapods

I'd been previously having some SSL issues with updating cocoapods and to fix it I updated rubygems. However, I now have a new error. Here's what I did and what I got:

`Alexs-MBP:~ alextyshka$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z`

I've read various things online about expired globalsign certificates but I REALLY don't want to mess up important stuff on my Mac. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the step described here http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update then run the following command

```
 sudo rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Answer (score 1):

I get RubyGems are not using expired certificates From http://help.rubygems.org.and find a issue very similar to you [ERROR: SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/25308-error-ssl-verification-error-at-depth-2-certificate-has-expired-10),maybe give you some help.

you can try:
 1. if you see the GlobalSign CA cert is expired (the 2014 one) you need to fetch the latest CA root certificate:[fetch the latest CA root certificate](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1426272-expiration-of-old-globalsign-2014-root-ca-certificate),
Please note that the expired GlobalSign certificate was refreshed nine years ago (in 2007). If you run into this please contact whoever maintains your canonical CA certificate list and point them to the above URL.
 2. done the following:

```
- Update ruby gems - http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/
- Downloaded and installed the new SSL certificate -     http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/
- Used RVM to update my system SSL certificates - http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html
```

Comment: Is the GlobalSign CA important for my computer, because as I said I don't want to mess up crucial stuff. Also, when I tried to get the rvm version it said I didn't have rvm

Comment: Can you please explain what a GlobalSign certificate is? Is it part of the OS? Part of Ruby? Part of the gem? I'm not very experienced wth coding and I just want to be able to do a Cocoapods tutorial.

Comment: GlobalSign certificate is ` Part of Ruby` ，According to the tip is your Ruby certificate has expired。

Comment: How is it even possible that the certificate expired when this computer is not that old and on the latest operating system?

Comment: Also, if I do mess up something with Ruby while doing this, is there a way to do a clean-slate reinstall of Ruby on Mac?

Comment: if RVM does not exist ，you can install a RVM，so that install Ruby， especially ，You can also install ruby by [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

Comment: 1，install [rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm) by `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` 2，install Ruby by ` rvm install you want rubyVersion` my mac is the latest `2.4.1` 3,after install finish, You Ruby query is already installed by `rvm list`  `rvm --default use you expect version` e.g.`rvm --default use 1.9.2` ,rvm remove extra version, next test whether it install right by `ruby -v`,

Comment: then install [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) , 1, If your computer's gem is too old, you can try to use the following command to upgrade the gem:Input the following command in the Terminal `sudo gem update --system` 2,sudo gem install  cocoapods

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just wondering: could I avoid all this by installing the cocoapods mac app? Would the Mac app be running the latest version or the version installed on my system?

Comment: no need, Cocoapods don't need to install the latest version,it is just a tool  to manage 3rd party library，But the cocoapods version below 1.0.0 Whether can use is not clear。

Comment: This whole question is here because I do need to install the latest version

Comment: At least more than 1.0.0,

Comment: look at [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNyO2.png),he means 0.0.39 is not maintenance, so suggest  install 1.0.0 version above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I even reinstalled cocoapods. Finally I found my gem source is no longer in use, so I find a new one and update the gem sources.

`$ gem sources --add new_side --remove old_side`